# PHP Preg_Match, составить регулярку

Tags: preg_match, php, парсер, html

Здравствуйте, использую php, хочу сделать некий парсер из html текста, 1 сообщения...
Сообщение скрыто между тегами

```
<div id="check_msg" class="error"> и </div>
```

использую:

```
preg_match('/<div id="check_msg" class="error">([^<]+)<\/div>/i', $check, $error)
```

но не работает, помогите :)

Comment: Стандартный ответ: то да сё, используйте HTML-парсер вместо регулярок, например, [Symfony/DomCrawler](https://github.com/symfony/DomCrawler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'#<div id="check_msg" class="error">(.*)</div>#iu'
```

Comment: @RichB, а что ж делать, если в строке будет еще что-нибудь?

    $str = '<div id="check_msg" class="error">Однажды, в студёную</div>
        <div id="other_block">Я из лесу вышел; был сильный мороз.</div>';

Answer (score 0):

Используйте SimpleParserDOM - c ним легче работать, и возьмете все что вам надо.

Comment: Скрипт 20 строк, он не стоит доп. библиотек

Comment: @Ek1FoX, лол